# Connecting a NVIDIA GeFORCE 6200 to a digital TV

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have connected it with a straight VGA to VGA cable and most of the time there is no sound.
I expected this however I can not see any sound output connection on the video card or the PC HP workstation 6300.
There is a jack plug on the front but this seems to be dead could it be switched off by the NVIDIA card?

Comment: Does your computer feature a HDMI output?

Answer (score 1):

That card itself is unlikely to have audio out.

You will have to use the regular sound output mini-jack on the back of the computer. If there are several identical-looking sockets, it will be the one with a light green ring round it.

Answer (score 1):

*Standard* VGA cables are not sufficient to transfer sound, and I doubt your graphics card supports it either.

Your best bet is to use VGA cable for image and audio jack cable for sound.

> Jack plug on the front seems to be dead

Right click your Sound icon on the taskbar and click **Playback devices**. 
Right click somewhere in the empty field and mark the checkbox for seeing disabled devices. If anything comes up, try enabling that device.

Also right click your Sound icon again and click **Open Volume Mixer**. Change between every device in the list and make sure it's not muted.

Or for a quick solution, connect it to the back